# unable to find package 'postgresql-12-citus-9.1'

Tags: 19.04, postgresql, citus

I am following this [documentation](http://docs.citusdata.com/en/v9.1/installation/single_machine_debian.html) to install PostgreSQL and Citus extension:

```
# Add Citus repository for package manager
curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/deb.sh | sudo bash

# install the server and initialize db
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12-citus-9.1
```

and I get:

[image]

I have look though the bash script and it seems to do what it needs. Could anyone tell why the package is not  found?

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on virtual machine using Hyper-V under Windows 10. Also, I have PostgreSQL 12 install and running:

[image]

Comment: They probably don't build packages for non-LTS releases. Besides, Ubuntu 19.04 has reached it end of life yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Citus does only support LTS versions (16.04 & 18.04) of Ubuntu currently. Also, as @Daniel Vérité  said, 19.04 has reached its EOL.